# questions of using parameters like I(...) in lmer-based modeling

Tags: r

I once saw the GLMM modeling building process using the following script:

```
dative.glmm8 <- lmer(RealizationOfRecipient ~ AnimacyOfRec + DefinOfRec +
PronomOfRec * PronomOfTheme + I(AccessOfRec=="given") + AnimacyOfTheme + DefinOfTheme +
I(AccessOfTheme=="given") + log(RatioOfLengthsThemeOverRecipient) + (1|Verb),      
family="binomial")
```

I do not understand the passed argument of "I(AccessOfTheme=="given")"? What is the physical meaning of this kind of argument setting?

Comment: If you're going to downvote - you should identify why. Just courtesy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is not actually `lmer`-specific, but applies to all model formulas in R. In a formula context, `I()` stands for "insulate": from http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf ,

> I(M ) Insulate M. Inside M all operators have their normal arithmetic
>   meaning, and
>        that term appears in the model matrix.

This is essentially creating a dummy (0/1) variable on the fly for `AccessOfRec` being equal to "given" (1) or anything else (0).

You could also do this by creating the variable beforehand, e.g. `AccessOfRec_given <- (AccessOfRec=="given")`, and then using the derived variable in the formula.

By the way, I would **strongly** recommend using the `data` argument to `lmer`, rather than either using variables from the global workspace or `attach()`ing data frames.

Comment: Ben,can you elaborate more on how to use data argument to lmer? Some examples may be helpful. Thanks.